# Read all registry values with name

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am writing one converted in Delphi, where old program have saved path to files. So I have to get to this files and they paths are in registry, the follow like this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE-> Company->Program-> Pos1, Stack, Pop
```

So under Program there are few registry maps like `Pos1`, `Stack`, `Po`p etc, and each of them have attribute there called `WorkStation` which is path I need to get. So I am looking is there are way that I scan thrue all and get this paths? Or do I need to know every path of registry?

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry) where you will find `TRegistry.GetKeyNames`. Do be wise to the registry redirector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enumerate all sub key names, you can use the `GetKeyNames()` method of the `TRegistry` class in the `Registry` unit.  You can then loop through the subkeys, opening each one and reading its `WorkStation` value.

```
uses
  ...,
  Registry,
  Classes;

var
  registry : TRegistry;
  subKeysNames : TStringList;
  WorkStation : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  registry := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    subKeysNames := TStringList.Create; 
    try
      registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('\Software\Company\Program') then
      begin
        registry.GetKeyNames(subKeysNames);
        CloseKey;
      end;
      for i := 0 to subKeysNames.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('\Software\Company\Program\' + subKeysNames[i]) then
        begin
          WorkStation := registry.ReadString('WorkStation');
          registry.CloseKey;
          if WorkStation <> '' then
          begin
            // use WorkStation as needed...
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      subKeysNames.Free;
    end;
  finally
    registry.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thats good, but problem is that i dont know how many sub key names are there, it could be 1 or 2 or more then 5 too.

Comment: @HyperX `subkeyNames.count` will tell you how many. It's a TStringList, you know :)

Comment: @HyperX  I add code to show how to fetch sub key count and names

Comment: @STBLand: you showed the code to get the subkey names, but not the code to actually open the subkeys and read values from them.  I added that code to your answer.